# How to save a pointer address, so that another pointer can continue working on it?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, shared-memory

Is there a way to store the address of a pointer into an arbitrary variable (e.g. an `int`) and to use this variable again to assign the address of a second pointer?

I know you can easily do

```
int* p1;
int* p2;
p2 = p1;
```

**What I'm looking for is something like this**

```
int* p1;
int* p2;
long addr_p1 = (long)p1;
p2 = doMagicCast(addr_p1);
```

Thanks for any advise

Comment: Why does your addr_p1 have to be a long? Why can't it be an int*?

Comment: Are you looking for [`std::uintptr_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)? Though even so, storing pointer addresses is pretty risky business, you should explain why you need this

Comment: The `doMagicCast` is actually simply `(int*)`. This will compile but it is not guaranteed to work because the size of a pointer may be different from the size of a `long`. Consider also the two previous comments.

Comment: because the complexity of the application, I would do the usual way if I **could** do it that way

Comment: @MichaelWalz actually, it's `reinterpret_cast`, which should also replace `(long)`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Why isn't it `static_cast<int*>`?

Comment: it is completely unclear to me what you want to do. Are you maybe looking for `void*`?

Comment: @iBug actually `reinterpret_cast` should be used, `static_cast` is too restrictive, it won't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct C++ way:

```
#include <cinttypes>

int main() {
  int* p1;
  int* p2;
  std::uintptr_t addr_p1 = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(p1);
  p2 = reinterpret_cast<int*>(addr_p1);
}
```

You need to use `std::uintptr_t` instead of `long` because there is no guarantee that a `long` can hold a pointer.

But on 32 bit platform (where `long` and pointers usually have 32 bits) your initial approach using long may work.

Comment: thanks I wasn't aware of the `long`-issue. Why is it risky to do it that way? Imagine I can 100% assure that the address and everything within this range won't be triggered by anything different but of these two pointers - Do i have to expect occasionally influences from outside of my program? Or is it just bad coding?

Comment: It's just bad coding. On 32 bit platforms `uintptr_t` is usually a `typedef unsigned int uintptr_t;`, so your code with `long` will certainly work on a 32 bit platform. But when you migrate your 32 bit application to the 64 bit world some time in the future, you'll regret using `long` instead of `std::uintptr_t`.

Comment: this is it, kind regards